# How do I use label and display for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, label

I am using few forms to get the input and I need to make a review form where people can review their information. It should be ADA compliant. I am using  tags in the forms. Now, in the review form, I need  to use the label tags as well. I wrote it like this
but the label and displayfor are not working together and when I use a ADA tool, it shows an error "A form label is present, but it is not associated with any form". Could you suggest me what am I doing wrong?

```
<label for="reviewFirstName">First Name</label> 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NameFirst,new{id = "reviewFirstName" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a label with a disabled input field..?

```
<label>First Name</label>&emsp;
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NameFirst, new { id="reviewFirstName" disabled="true" })
```

Or do the users need to be able to alter their in-putted information?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with disabled is that I will not be able to put the focus on that textbox. So, I am using @readonly, and its working fine. The user will be using that screen for review only.